# Сумма положительных элементов между двумя отрицательными

Tags: c++

Задача в том, чтобы найти сумму элементов расположенных между первым и вторым отрицательными элементами, но я немного напортачил и полностью запутался.

```
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    randomize();
    Edit1->Text = IntToStr(n);
    StringGrid1->ColCount = n;
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
        StringGrid1->Cells[i][0] = IntToStr(random(21) - 10);
    Label3->Hide();
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int i, k, s = 0, a[10];
    for(i = 0;i<n;i++)
        a[i] = StrToInt(StringGrid1->Cells[i][0]);
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        if(a[i] <= 0)
            k = i;
    for(i = k + 1;i<n;i++)
        s += a[i];
    Label3->Show();
    Label3->Caption = IntToStr(s);
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    n = StrToInt(Edit1->Text);
    if(n>10)
    {
        ShowMessage("Максимальное количество - 10.");
        n = 10;
        Edit1->Text = "10";
    }
    StringGrid1->ColCount = n;
    for(int i = 0;i<n;i++)
    {
        StringGrid1->Cells[i][0] = IntToStr(random(21) - 10);
        Label3->Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы уточнить вопрос - пример того, что вы подаёте на вход, что ожидаете получить и что получаете. А так же объясните смысл метода `Button1Click`.

Comment: Мне найти сумму элементов расположенных между первым и вторым отрицательными элементами, но на выходе я получаю лишь числа, которые не соответствуют моей задачей.
Button1Click - задает размер n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для начала сразу скажу: в следующий раз постарайтесь в вопросе приводить только код, относящийся непосредственно к вопросу. В вашем случае `Button1Click`, `TForm1` и заполнение массива числами не имеет отношение к вопросу, что только ухудшает читаемость и желание разбираться в вопросе.

Теперь к вопросу. Сначала приведу рабочий пример:

```
int i = 0, s = 0, n = 10, a[10];
// каким-либо образом заполняем массив а
while ((a[i] >= 0) && (i < n)) { // тут мы находим индекс первого отрицательного элемента
    i++;
}
i++; // увеличиваем счетчик на 1, то есть устанавливаем его на индекс первого элемента, который надо сложить
while ((a[i] >= 0) && (i < n)) { // далее суммируем элементы, пока не доходим до следующего отрицательного
    s += a[i];
    i++;
}
// далее вы выводите куда-то s
```

---

Теперь разберем ваш код. За нахождение заданной суммы у вас отвечает код:

```
int i, k, s = 0, a[10];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if(a[i] <= 0)
        k = i;
for(i = k + 1; i < n;i++)
    s += a[i];
```

Первая ошибка: вы в сравнение используете `<=`, то есть вы проверяете число, не является ли число положительным, хотя в условии говорили про отрицательные (надо или использовать `<`, или исправить условие).

Далее, предположим, мы как-то уже заполнили массив `a` числами. Рассмотрим первый цикл:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    if(a[i] <= 0)
        k = i;
```

Здесь вы при нахождении отрицательного элемента присваиваете его индекс переменной `k`, но этот цикл продолжает выполняться и после нахождения первого элемента, то есть в итоге у вас в `k` будет индекс ПОСЛЕДНЕГО отрицательного элемента в массиве. Вам же после первого присвоения нужно прервать выполнение цикла:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if(a[i] < 0) {
        k = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

Теперь рассмотрим второй цикл:

```
for(i = k + 1; i < n;i++)
    s += a[i];
```

Этот же цикл вообще тупо суммирует все числа от элемента с индексом `k + 1` до конца. Тут точно также нужно проверять, что текущее число неотрицательное, и, если оно отрицательное, прерывать цикл:

```
for(int i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
    if(a[i] < 0) {
        break;
    }
    s += a[i];
}
```

Надеюсь этот небольшой разбор поможет вам разобраться в том, что вы написали и не повторять таких ошибок в будущем.

Comment: Спасибо, вы многое мне разъяснили, но к сожалению, программа все еще не работает должным образом. В ответе просто выдается 0.

Comment: @Alex https://ideone.com/bGUOS3 сам алгоритм рабочий, можете убедиться. Скорее всего проблема во вводе данных. попробуйте посмотреть, что у вас оказывается в массиве `а` перед работой алгоритма. Я больше чем уверен, что там будет не то, что вы вводили.

Comment: Использую компонент StringGrid (Builder 6.0), который сам заполняет массив, вряд ли в проблема в нем