# Отрицательное числов вместо ответа

Tags: c++

Задача в том, чтобы найти сумму элементов расположенных между первым и вторым отрицательными элементами, но по какой-то причине, выводится большое отрицательное число, вместо ответа.

```
int i, k, s = 0, a[10];
for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    if(a[i] < 0)
    {
        k = i;
        break;
    }

{
    for(i = k + 1;i<n;i++)
        s += a[i];
}
```

Comment: вопрос - как у вас инициализированы `n` и собственно сам массив?

Comment: @user204021, `a` не инициализирован, его элементы ссылаются на случайные адреса, из-за этого сами значения непредсказуемы. Что с `n` — вообще не ясно.

Comment: Это у вас задание одно на всю группу? Второй идентичный вопрос за день и абсолютно те же проблемы. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/497989/%D0%A1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8/498000#498000

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой код (вы забыли условие остановки на 2-м отрицательном элементе):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int n = 10;
    int k, s = 0, a[n] = {1, 2, -3, 4, 5, 6, -7, 8, 9, 10};
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if(a[i] < 0) {
            k = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    for(int i = k + 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (a[i] < 0) {
            break;
        }
        s += a[i];
    }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Работаю через Builder 6 и использую компонент StringGrid, поэтому не смог записать массив, как в вашем коде. Все остальные изменения не помогли, число теперь стало положительным, но все таким же большим.

Comment: @user204021 А вы  пробовали посмотреть, что у вас в массиве есть перед тем, как считать что-либо? Может, вы его ничем не заполнили и там просто мусор?

Comment: @user204021 моя программа работает корректно, дело в ваших руках. Попробуйте **[протестить тут](https://www.codechef.com/ide)**, например, и поймете, что все работает корректно.